# Is this a correct way to reuse a tf.slim graph for validation during training?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to do validation after every epoch during training.

I am creating the graphs as follows :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from networks import densenet
from networks.densenet_utils import dense_arg_scope

with tf.variable_scope('scope') as scope:
    with slim.arg_scope(dense_arg_scope()):
        logits_train, _ = densenet(images, blocks=networks[
            'densenet_265'], num_classes=1000, data_name='imagenet', is_training=True, scope='densenet265',
                                 reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    with slim.arg_scope(dense_arg_scope()):
        logits_val, _ = densenet(images, blocks=networks[
            'densenet_265'], num_classes=1000, data_name='imagenet', is_training=False, scope='densenet265',
                                 reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
```

And for getting the `logits` during training or validation, I do the following :

```
is_training = tf.Variable(True, trainable=False, dtype=tf.bool)
training_mode = tf.assign(is_training, True)
validation_mode = tf.assign(is_training, False)
logits = tf.cond(tf.equal(is_training, tf.constant(True, dtype=tf.bool)), lambda: logits_train,
                     lambda: logits_val)
```

However when I run my code, I get OOM error. I am sure that this is not because of a large batch size. This is because, previously I was making a blunder and was using the same graph during training and validation. At that time with a batch size of `32` with image size `224x224x3`, the code was running quite fine.

I am suspecting that I am making some mistake in trying to reuse the graph during validation with `is_training=False`.

The code for densenet has been taken from the following two files :
[densenet_utils.py](https://github.com/NanqingD/DenseNet-Tensorflow/blob/master/densenet_utils.py)
[densenet.py](https://github.com/NanqingD/DenseNet-Tensorflow/blob/master/densenet_v1.py)

Answer (score 2):

You're creating two separate networks in logits_train and logits_val, so this takes up double the memory your network would take otherwise. (I'm assuming it's set up properly and variables are shared correctly, that could be another issue, but that wouldn't probably cause OOM, the large data are the activations, not the weights.)

There is no need for doing this. Use the same network `logits_train` for validation as well. Turns out the parameter `is_training` can take a boolean scalar tensor as well, so you can switch training or inference mode on the fly.

So right where you set up your `images` placeholder, have this line as next:

```
training_mode = tf.placeholder( shape = None, dtype = tf.bool )
```

Then in the above code, set up your network like this:

```
logits_train, _ = densenet(images, blocks=networks['densenet_265'],
    num_classes=1000, data_name='imagenet', is_training=training_mode,
    scope='densenet265', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
```

Note that the `is_training` argument's value is populated with the tensor `training_mode` above!

And then when you do the `sess.run( [ ... ] )` command (not visible in your code above) you should include the `training_mode` in your `feed_dict` like so (pseudo code):

```
result = sess.run( [ ??? ], feed_dict = { images : ???, training_mode : True / False } )
```

Note that the `training_mode` tensor is now populated with False or True based on whether you're doing training.

This is based on my research of the **batch_normalization** and **dropout** layers.

Comment: Variable sharing was my idea. The `densenet` network indeed has batch normalization and dropout layers. So, during inference I do need to disable them. 
My main doubt was that considering the fact that I am using `reuse_variables()` from `variable_scope`, where exactly is the mistake in the graph sharing ?

Comment: I see no mistake in variable sharing, that was just a side comment, because when I did something similar, I had some issues with that. :) I see no error in your code in that respect.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still builds separate graphs as I just found out from my code. I would still like to know, how can I just use the same graph for inference without going into a different process.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I agree with your latest answer. It is not worth the effort to modify slim layers. However, it could be good if there could be two graphs with shared weights, except that they differ in `is_training` argument. This is what I am trying to do. But it seems it is either not possible or I am doing it the wrong way. I tested my code and I found that because of `is_training=False` a new graph is being created. I don't understand this.

Comment: Did more research and you're lucky somebody implemented just what you need! I also upvoted your question because I actually learned something new while doing the research.

Comment: I have used the placeholder approach before posting this question. It does not work. It seems that setting `is_training=False` leads to the creation of a separate graph.